# Reading and writing a csv file in one line

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have below code

```
import pandas as pd
(pd.read_csv('https://www.stats.govt.nz/assets/Uploads/Business-financial-data/Business-financial-data-September-2022-quarter/Download-data/business-financial-data-september-2022-quarter-csv.zip')
    .assign(New = lambda x : 'NEW')
    .apply(lambda x : x.to_csv(x['New'].values[0] + '_File.csv')))
```

Basically, I wanted to use **chain rule** to read and write a `csv` file, after some modification using above lines of code. Final file name is chosen dynamically based on some value of chosen column. However this unfortunately is failing.

Could you please help to correct above code?

Comment: "some value" - it's not *some* in your code. it's certain `x['New'].values[0]`

Comment: I'm getting `KeyError: 'New'` - is this what you get too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) :

```
(pd.read_csv('https://www.stats...quarter-csv.zip')
    .assign(New = lambda x : 'NEW')
    .pipe(lambda x: x.to_csv(x['New'].iat[0] + '_File.csv'))) # with `index=False`?
```